# Node won't install Ionic without errors on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, ionic-framework

The installation won't complete without errors, and as a result, Ionic does not function correctly. I've tried removing and reinstalling several times with no success, and none of the tips I found have solved the problem.

I would be greatful for input.

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
Password:
/usr/local/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v51-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@7.0.0 (node-v51 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v7.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.0.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v7.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.0.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ ionic@3.20.0
updated 1 package in 11.239s
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by reinstalling nodejs. Not quite sure what caused the problem in the first place.